# XCode5 uses gcc48 even if default apple llvm 5.0 selected

Tags: xcode, llvm, homebrew

After installation of xcode 5, gcc4.8 (with homebrew) and xcode command line tools, the ide tries to use /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 and fails with exit code 1, even if in the build options there is "Default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.0)" selected.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

On mi Lion homebrew fail build, but I build with this config with apple llvm-gcc42:

success gmp:

```
CFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CPPFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CXXFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LDFLAGS="-m32 -m64" ./configure   --prefix=/usr/local   --enable-cxx --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --host=none-apple-darwin --enable-fat=yes
```

success mpfr:

```
CFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CPPFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CXXFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LDFLAGS="-m32 -m64" ./configure   --prefix=/usr/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --host=none-apple-darwin
```

success mpc:

```
CFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CPPFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CXXFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LDFLAGS="-m32 -m64" ./configure   --prefix=/usr/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --host=none-apple-darwin
```

success isl:

```
CFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CPPFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CXXFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LDFLAGS="-m32 -m64" ./configure   --prefix=/usr/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --host=none-apple-darwin   --enable-portable-binary
```

success cloog:

```
CFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CPPFLAGS="-m32 -m64" CXXFLAGS="-m32 -m64" LFLAGS="-m32 -m64 -L/usr/local/lib" LDFLAGS="-m32 -m64 -L/usr/local/lib" ./configure   --prefix=/usr/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin --host=none-apple-darwin   --enable-portable-binary  --with-isl-prefix=/usr/local
```

success gcc 4.8.1:

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++  --build=x86_64-apple-darwin  --target=x86_64-apple-darwin --with-system-zlib  --enable-multilib  --enable-objc-gc  --enable-lto  --enable-ld=yes  --enable-bootstrap --enable-gold=yes CC="/usr/bin/gcc" CXX="/usr/bin/g++" CFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" CXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" CPPFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" OBJCFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" OBJCXXFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" LFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5" LDFLAGS="-mmacosx-version-min=10.5"
```

You need download all sources, don't use any macports and brew.

Ypu can check build program with this gcc-4.8.1 from http://chomikuj.pl/ydk2/wxwidgets+Mac+OS+X/wxphp/main.wxphp.app.bundle.10.6.i386,3523603473.zip this is only my test build but checked on L and ML.

Edit...
And after you can try add in ~/.profile:

```
alias gcc=/usr/local/bin/gcc
alias cc=/usr/local/bin/gcc
alias g++=/usr/local/bin/g++
alias c++=/usr/local/bin/c++
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++   
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
```

/opt/bin is optional, only if have you a binary there.
But first need to be /usr/local/bin where you have gcc installed if as first add /usr/bin, /usr/bin/gcc is used for command gcc

For Apple gcc simple in shell:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
export CPP=/usr/bin/cpp
export LD=/usr/bin/ld
alias c++=/usr/bin/c++
alias g++=/usr/bin/g++
alias gcc=/usr/bin/gcc
alias cpp=/usr/bin/cpp
alias cc=/usr/bin/cc
```